# Spaces being converted to %20 in Android output

Tags: android, spaces

We have this Android code that is sending text to a collector:

```
public void sendHello() {
    s.link = "None";
    s.track("App Home Page - Hello all");
}
```

The output, though, contains %20 instead of spaces so we are ending up with something like this:

```
App%20Home%20Page%20-%20Helloall
```

Does anyone know how to prevent the spaces being converted or what is causing it?

Comment: What does `s.track(String)` do with the input? You'll need to post the code that produces the output, then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it'd be nice to know the type of `s`. But, as a shot in the dark, you could use URLDecoder's [decode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) method.